# Split a string into array and replace first character with number

Tags: php

I have a personal id like below:

```
$personal_id = 'I91120056N';
$verify = array_merge(array_fill(0, 1, 'W'), array_combine(range(1, 22),range('A','V'))); #0-22 #A-W 0=W
$splitID = str_split($personal_id,1);
$firstletter = array_search($splitID[0], $verify);
```

I'm splitting the id into an array that looks like :

```
$splitID = Array
(
    [0] => I
    [1] => 9
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 2
    [5] => 0
    [6] => 0
    [7] => 5
    [8] => 6
    [9] => N
)
```

Now I want to replace the `I` with a number that `$firstletter` gives and merge it into the same array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood your question correctly this should solve your problem:
`$arr[0] = $firstletter;
$output = implode(',',$arr)`